# What is the sum of the following arithmetic series?

Tags: calculus, analysis

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3^n+5^n}{6^n}$$

In order to solve this problem I need to use the following formula (specified in the exam):

$$\sum_{0}^\infty {a_1}{q^n} = \frac{a_1}{1-q}$$

I know how to solve this kind of example, but can't start it, since I don't know what to do with the numerator. Unfortunately there isn't any basic rules of exponentiation I could use since there is a summation in the numerator.

Comment: Hint: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3^n+5^n}{6^n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3^n}{6^n} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5^n}{6^n}$$

Comment: That is **not** an "arithmetic sequence", it is, as Kenny Lau said, the sum of two geometric sequences.

Comment: @KennyLau Thanks for the hint, it's so trivial I actually feel bad about the question. Thanks a lot tho!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3^n+5^n}{6^n} \\
S &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3^n}{6^n} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5^n}{6^n} \\
S &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^n \\
S &= \dfrac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}} + \dfrac{\frac{5}{6}}{1-\frac{5}{6}} \\
S &= 1 + 5 = 6\\
\end{align}$$

The closed form of the geometric sequence in this case can be derived as follows:

Let $ g = \sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n = r + r^2 + r^3 + ...$

Then $rg = r^2 + r^3 + r^4 + ...$

Subtract the two and see that $g-rg = r$, or $g \cdot (1-r) = r$, or $g = \dfrac{r}{1-r}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually over complicated the problem for myself with a ton of writing. I see your point, I think the exam itself is not very well formulated on my paper.